# Community♦ decisions - sometimes remarkably rapid

Tags: support, closed-questions, community-moderation

After a quick couple of comments under a new question, I flagged it as a dupe of a similar question, which the OP seemed happy with.

[How to use other key combination to replace ⌘W?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363213/how-to-use-other-key-combination-to-replace-w#363213)

Within a minute, Community♦ agreed with me & closed as a dupe.

Whilst I'm fine with this decision, I was surprised by the speed at which it made the call - based on, as far as I can tell, merely my say-so.

Do we know by what criteria Community♦ makes this type of value judgement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of closing duplicates, Community acts on behalf of the author of the question.

When a question receives a vote to close as duplicate, the author of the question is prompted that it is suspected their question is a duplicate. The author then has the ability to agree with the duplicate and have their question marked as such, or to disagree and edit the question. If the author chooses the former option, the question is closed as duplicate by Community.

> [image]

[New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/222623)

Comment: Ahh... yes. I'd completely forgotten about that, been a long time since I saw it. Thanks.